# Editing a file in Azure Blob Storage with an API

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage

Here is my scenario.

I have placed a config file (.xml) into an Azure Blob Storage container

I want to edit that xml file and update/add content to it.

I want to deploy an api to an azure app service that will do that.

I built an api that runs locally that handles this but that isn't exactly going to cut it as a cloud application. This particular iteration is a NODEjs api that uses the Cheerio and File-System modules in order to manipulate and read the file respectively.

How can I retool this to be work with a file that lives in Azure blob storage?

note: Are azure blobs the best place to start with the file even? Is there a better place to put it?

I found this but it isn't exactly what I am after.....[Azure Edit blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27851131/azure-edit-blob)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the data stored in blob is XML (in other words string type), instead of using `getBlobToStream` method, you can use [`getBlobToText`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/blob/master/lib/services/blob/blobservice.core.js#L1845) method, manipulate the string, and then upload that updated string using [`createBlockBlobFromText`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/blob/master/lib/services/blob/blobservice.core.js#L3207).

Here's the pseudo code:

```
blobService.getBlobToText('mycontainer', 'taskblob', function(error, result, response) {
    if (error) {
        console.log('Error in reading blob');
        console.error(error);
    } else {
        var blobText = result;//It 
        var xmlContent = someMethodToConvertStringToXml(blobText);//Convert string to XML if it is easier to manipulate
        var updatedBlobText = someMethodToEditXmlContentAndReturnString(xmlContent);
        //Reupload blob
        blobService.createBlockBlobFromText('mycontainer', 'taskblob', updatedBlobText, function(error, result, response) {
            if (error) {
                console.log('Error in updating blob');
                console.error(error);
            } else {
                console.log('Blob updated successfully');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply refactor your code to use the Azure Storage SDK for Node.js https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node

Comment: So I saw that and I thought that might work but I could exactly see how.  


Take this piece here....  

blobService.getBlobToStream('mycontainer', 'taskblob', fs.createWriteStream('output.txt'), function(error, result, response))  


I can do that and get the file out of blob storage but it just ends up as a local file on my machine as if I downloaded it. Am I misunderstanding/doing something wrong there?