# Is there any way to read and modify the contents of .ini file in azure blob storage only , without downloading it in the local using python?

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

Is there any way If I want to modify the contents of a .ini file inside the azure blob storage and update it there without having the need to download it in the local using python ?

Comment: There is no [tag:python] in this question.

Comment: @PeterWood it is there now , if you know how to achieve this ask , it would be really helpful. Thank you

Comment: Please refer this  SO Thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27851131/azure-edit-blob

Comment: @KadamSolanki please take the [tour], read about [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I have tested in my environment.

You can use the below python script to read and modify the contents of .ini file in Azure Blob Storage using python :

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
connect_str = "connection string of storage account"
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container="containerName", blob="iniFileName")
blob_download = blob_client.download_blob()
blob_content = blob_download.readall()
print(blob_content)
blob_content="content you want to update"
blob_client.upload_blob(blob_content, overwrite=True)
```

Before modifying, the file content was :

[image]

After modifying, the file content is :

[image]